# Gridalicious append function doesn't work

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

In my app, I use gridalicious, but I can't seem to use this code to append a div into my grid.

```
$('#append').click(function(){
    $('#posts-list').gridalicious('append','<div class="item" style="height: 100px; background-color: black;"></div>');
});
```

Why is the gridalicious append function not working?

For reference: http://suprb.com/apps/gridalicious/

Comment: any error messages in the console?

Comment: There aren't any errors in the console

Comment: update jquery version. Try to use latest

Answer (score 0):

This will work for you:

```
$('#append').click(function(){
    $('#posts-list').gridalicious('append',$('<div class="item" style="height: 100px; background-color: black;"></div>'));
});
```